# Why does mapping <ESC> start command line Vim in Replace mode?

Tags: vim, terminal

I was having an issue where starting Vim from the command line was starting in Replace mode. I finally narrowed it down to this line in my config:

```
nnoremap <ESC>         :noh<return><ESC>
```

If I change the key to anything other than  like `nnoremap <space><space><space>` (just to test… I would never leave it like this.), I do not see the behavior. If I use MacVim rather than command line Vim, I don't see it either. I'm using iTerm 2 with `xterm-256color` terminal and zsh as my shell type since that seems like it could be relevant.

Anyone have an idea what I should be looking at to troubleshoot this? The answer is of course welcome, but if you can also share where I should be thinking about this issue coming from it might help me troubleshoot similar things in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI Escape sequences that are used by the terminal all start with Escape (`^[`), and as Vim is using those to communicate with the terminal, it gets confused when you map `<Esc>`. That's also why there are no problems in MacVim (and GVIM); those do not use the terminal and have different I/O channels.

Mapping `<Esc>` in terminal Vim is just looking for trouble; please just choose another key.